# How to control event handling rate with a serverless stack

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless, aws-serverless

I have to fetch an external API that has a limitation of a few hundred req/min, to process an unknown amount of events : last week events ( events i store as dynamoDB objects  ), and call this API with each of them.

My first idea is to do the following :

- Get all the events for a specific day from dynamo ( but i could get fewer )
- Put those events in an SQS queue
- have SQS Events trigger another lambda with a reserved concurrency set low enough ( let's say to 2 ) that will request the API.
  Since the lambda has a ~100ms duration, will I have a maximum of 20 req/sec here ?

I my logic correct here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution generally makes sense. One of the other things you should be aware of is the `VisibilityTimeout` on the SQS queue. This basically means

> hide anything that's been read for ${VisibilityTimeout} seconds, before making it visible for processing again

Keep in mind if you get an error in your Lambda, the queue message will just stay in the queue. For more on that, [see this article](https://dev.to/piczmar_0/error-handling-in-aws-lambda-trigger-by-sqs-events-3amp), which I found helpful.

The other approach you could take if you still run into throttling issues with your external API is to set up a CloudWatch event that wakes up every so often (let's say every 5 minutes) and explicitly calls your lambda. You'd need to retrofit your Lambda to **explicitly read messages from the queue**, and then process them. This would give you a little more control to "sip" messages using the [receiveMessage method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#receiveMessage-property) on the SQS SDK.